# JS regular expression Allow alphanumeric characters and . , " ( ) - _ # : ; * @ & not remaining +, =, $, !, <, >, `, ~, {, }, |,\,?, ~

Tags: javascript

i tried with below pattern

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^[ A-Za-z0-9.,()-_#:;*@&]*$");
console.log(pattern.test("asda ?"));// giving true
```

but with, i need to get the false.
Please provides regExp to allow **alphanumeric characters and  . , " ( ) - _ # : ; * @ &** not remaining special chars  **+, =, $, !, <, >, `, ~, {, }, |,?, ~**

Comment: Why `new RegExp("...")` vs. `/.../`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `-` because otherwise it allows all characters in the range between `)` and `_`, `?` happens to be in that range.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^[ A-Za-z0-9.,()\\-_#:;*@&]*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/"^[ A-Za-z0-9.,()-_#:;*@&]*$"/);
console.log(pattern.test("asda ?"));// giving true
```

this should allow your variable to accept universal characters

Comment: The `regex` you suggested changes the meaning of the `regex` posted in the question completely. How does it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

A dash (`-`) in the middle of a character class (`[...]`) means interval.
`A-Z` means all characters between and including `A` and `Z`.
The same way, `)-_` does not mean any of `)`, `-` and `_` but all characters between `)` and `_`. This range includes digits, uppercase letters and a lot of other characters you want to exclude (`+`, `<`, ,`>`, `?` etc). Check the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to find the complete list.

In order to prevent the dash (`-`) to have a special meaning in a character class you can put it as the last character in the class.

Use [the following fragment of code](https://repl.it/repls/AlphanumericCaringBooleanalgebra) in your browser to see how the `regex` matches (or doesn't match) the printable ASCII characters:

```
let pattern = new RegExp("^[ A-Za-z0-9.,()_#:;*@&-]*$");

for (let i = ' '.charCodeAt(0); i < '~'.charCodeAt(0); i ++) {
  console.log(`'${String.fromCharCode(i)}': ${pattern.test(String.fromCharCode(i))}`);
}
```